# how to create an application that gives a command in / system / xbin

Tags: android, system

How can I create an application that has the function to execute a command in a specific place?
This application should run the command in / system / xbin. The command that I have to give is: (udpxy-p 4022).
And this application should start after the boot is completed.

if anyone knows another way to do this and can help me.
I read something about the init.rc or shellscript, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I believe this is possible. You can either modify the init file https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot

Or use the [Script Manager - SManager App](http://www.technohunk.com/2013/02/how-to-execute-a-command-at-boot-android/)

Just add something like:

```
cd /system/xbin
udpxy-p 4022
```